# Savon and Nokogiri parse result

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, savon

I´m using Savon and Nokogiri to parse SOAP responses.

This is my code:

```
response = client.call(:is_resource_available, message: message)     
isResourceAvailableXML = response.body[:is_resource_available_response][:out]
@logger.debug "response=" + isResourceAvailableXML.inspect  
isResourceAvailableParsed = Nokogiri::XML(isResourceAvailableXML)
isResourceAvailable = isResourceAvailableParsed.xpath("//resource")
@logger.debug "isResourceAvailable=" + isResourceAvailable.inspect      
bIsResourceAvailable = isResourceAvailable["isavailable"]
```

This is the log:

```
response="<resource id=\"1188200267800225\" isavailable=\"1\" />"
isResourceAvailable=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd16d979fb8 name="resource" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd16d979db0 name="id" value="1188200267800225">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd16d979d9c name="isavailable" value="1">]>]
```

I´m getting this error: `TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I'm not getting an array but only a single node, so instead of

```
isResourceAvailable = isResourceAvailableParsed.xpath("//resource")
```

I should use

```
isResourceAvailable = isResourceAvailableParsed.at_xpath("//resource")
```